# bitset_to_array causing memory limit error in 64bit php

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

I'm trying to append data to a Zend_Search_Lucene index but I'm getting a memory limit error  on a line of on line 1584 of Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_SegmentInfo that has this

```
 $bitCount = count(bitset_to_array($delBytes));
```

It runs fine on our development servers, but when ported to another server that's when I get the error. The difference between the two is that the one that works is a 32-bit server and the one where it doesn't work is a 64-bit server. I suspect this is the reason and would like to know if anyone else encountered this issue and is there a patch available (I'm trying to avoid having to rework the solution to be 32-bit)

Comment: are you sure the php memory limit is the same on all machines?

Comment: Well on the machine I increased the limit to accomodate to the error but realized it was a deeer issue once I increased the limit to 512MB